# Python regex is hung up when creating a group and certain characters followed by digits

Tags: python, regex

I am getting a weird situation in Python 3. Attempting to find some characters (a-z) that have one period and space(s) in between followed by a section sign (0-2 times) followed by a space, followed by digits (1 or more times).

When running this in Python, I don't get a result. It just get hung up.

```
import re
string = "Guidelines on International Protection: Membership in a “Particular Social Group” Within the Context of Article 1A(2) of the 1951 Convention and/or its 1967 Protocol Relating to the Status 
    ...: of Refugees (UNHCR Guidelines), U.N. Doc. HCR/GIP/02/02 (May 7, 2002)"
regex = r'((?:[a-z]+\.{0,1}\s*)+)(§{0,2})\s+(\d+)'
compile = re.compile(regex, flags=re.IGNORECASE)  
re.findall(compile,string)
```

In https://regexr.com/, it actually gives me correct matches: https://regexr.com/53394

What is happening?

Comment: Your second sentence, which is crucial, is not clear. Please edit to make the requirement precise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An effective solution to your problem of *catastrophic backtracking* is to simulate an [atomic group](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-disambiguation.html#atomic) (not supported by Python's `re` module) by using a positive lookahead with a capture group:

```
(?=((?:[a-z]+\.?\s*)+))\1§{0,2}\s*\d+
```

with multiline and case-indifferent flags set. This avoids catastrophic backtracking as the lookahead is not subject to giving up characters.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/icHjRR/2/)

A cleaner way would be to use a [possessive quantifier](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#possessive) when matching one or more occurrences of a letter. One could use the regular expression

```
(?:[a-z]++\.?\s*)+§{0,2}\s*\d+
```

with multiline and case-indifferent flags set. Here the possessive modifier is indicated by `++`.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/icHjRR/1/)

Unfortunately, Python's `re` module does not support possessive modifiers, but its alternative [PyPi module](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) does.

Suppose we had used the regex `(?:[a-z]+\.?\s*)+§{0,2}\s*\d+`, which does not have a possessive modifier.

For the string

```
Within the Context. of Article 1A(2)
```

`[a-z]+` matches `Within the Context`, then `\.?\s*` matches `.`. The regex engine then continues trying to find a match for the entire regex. If it fails it will backtrack to consider alternatives and may return to the match of `[a-z]+`, at which point it would *give back* the character `t` (making that match `Within the Contex`), reset the regex engine's internal pointer right before the `t`, and once again continue forward.

The possessive modifier `++` in prevents the regex engine from giving up any characters in its original match of `Within the Context`, thereby avoid the catastrophic backtracking problem. Even where catastrophic backtracking is not an issue, possessive modifiers, where they can be used, can greatly improve efficiency.

Answer (score 2):

If you test your regex in a Python-compatible regex tester, you [will see](https://regex101.com/r/56rCxJ/2) it takes a huge amount of steps to complete matching and ends in *catastrophic backtracking*. This is caused by the `(?:[a-z]+\.{0,1}\s*)+` pattern that is not at the pattern end. It forces the regex engine to backtrack heavily when the consequent `(§{0,2})\s+(\d+)` is not found.

The fix is to **make the pattern match so that each subsequent pattern could not match the same text at the same location**:

```
([a-z]+(?:(?:\s*\.\s*|\s+)[a-z]+)*)(§{0,2})\s+(\d+)
 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/56rCxJ/3/)

Here, `(?:[a-z]+\.{0,1}\s*)+` is replaced with `[a-z]+(?:(?:\s*\.\s*|\s+)[a-z]+)*`:

- `[a-z]+` - 1+ ASCII letters (mind the `re.IGNORECASE` modifier you are using)
- `(?:(?:\s*\.\s*|\s+)[a-z]+)*` - 0 or more occurrences of

  - `(?:\s*\.\s*|\s+)` - a `.` enclosed with 0+ whitespaces or 1+ whitespaces
  - `[a-z]+` - 1+ ASCII letters.

Comment: Thanks @wiktor-stribiżew for the excellent explanation! I had a hunch it was due to catastrophic backtracking.